# How does FFMPEG change fps without dropping frames?

Tags: ffmpeg, frame-rate

Here I got a video which has the FPS 30, duration 10s, and has 300 frames. How could I turn the video to 25FPS without dropping frames.

I suppose the `-r` or `fps=fps=25` is kind of resampling method or not working.

My commands are like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -vf "scale=800:450, fps=25" output1.flv
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i intput.flv -filter:v fps=fps=25 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v high -f mp4 -vf scale=800:450 output2.mp4
```

The result is that `output1.flv` dropped frames, and `output2.mp4` didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

If you're re-encoding the video stream, then

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -i input.flv ...
```

If there's audio, you'll have to adjust its tempo as well by adding

```
-af atempo=0.834
```

where 0.834 is 25/30.